# Using purely XAML to set a Dependency Property of a Control on button click

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

So I'm still trying to figure out the limitations of WPF using MVVM.  Now I'd like to find out if it's possible to bind a button click to trigger a change on another controls dependency property without having to touch the code behind.  Here's a sample of my Xaml.

```
<xctk:WindowContainer>
    <xctk:ChildWindow IsModal="True" WindowStartupLocation="Center" WindowState="Open">
         <view:EditView/>
    </xctk:ChildWindow>
</xctk:WindowContainer>
```

Now in this edit view I have some fields and a submit and cancel button and it shares the same viewmodel as its parent.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Content="Submit"/>
    <Button Content="Cancel"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Now normally I would just make a command in the ViewModel to perform the behavior I want but then I thought wouldn't it be great if I could set the ChildWindow's WindowState property to Closed when I hit say the Cancel button?  I don't know if this can be easily done but I figured I'd ask as it seems like something that should be possible but my knowledge of WPF just isn't there yet.  I appreciate any input.

Comment: If you have the interaction/interactivity namespaces `Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core` you could just use `ChangePropertyAction` and easily do it with an EventTrigger, or if you'd rather hit the Close method, could just do a CallMethodAction

Comment: The WindowState property does not have a content called closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an `EventTrigger` with a `Storyboard`:

```
<xctk:WindowContainer>
    <xctk:ChildWindow x:Name="childWindow">
        <view:EditView/>
    </xctk:ChildWindow>
</xctk:WindowContainer>

...

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Content="Submit"/>
    <Button Content="Cancel">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="childWindow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="WindowState">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static xctk:WindowState.Closed}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
             </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

(*See http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/event-based-property-changes*)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply this was exactly what I what looking for, although I find it interesting you need to use a Storyboard for it.